# Cordova and Gitlab CI

Tags: cordova, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently using GitLab as my main repository for Cordova projects and PhoneGap Build for Continuous Integration, but these don't work together very well and as far as I am aware GitLab has its own builder.

Could you please tell me if such feature exists and if it does, what features should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly, it should have been possible by some built in way.

"Just a quick update, we have added the ability to link your PhoneGap Build account to an existing BitBucket or GitLab account. This will allow you to build your private BitBucket or GitLab hosted repository without having to resort to insecure basic authentication (yes people are doing that!)." (http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/04/11/bitbucket-and-gitlab-repo-oauth-supported/)

But I couldn't find this integration, to I wrote a script to automate the deployment from Gitlab's CI, Pipelines, to Phonegap. Here are the steps to set this up:

1. `npm install -D phonegap-build`
2. Have a script that uses phonegap-build to login and build the project in phonegap's cloud in your repository.

For example, the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var phonegapbuild = require('phonegap-build')

console.log('Logging in...')
phonegapbuild.login({
    username: process.env.PHONEGAP_BUILD_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PHONEGAP_BUILD_PASSWORD
}, function(e) {
    console.log('logged in!')
    var options = { platforms: ['android'], }

    if(e) error(e)
    else {
        console.log('Calling `build` function...')
        phonegapbuild.build(options, function(e) {
            if (e) error(e)
            else console.log('Success!')
        })
    }
})

const error = (err) => { console.error(err); process.exitCode = 1 }
```

3. Setup `Pipelines`, which is gitlab CI, to run your deploy script. Do so with a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml`, and have it specify the required job. I wrote mine while referencing the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html):

   variables:
     GIT_DEPTH: "1"
   dev:
     image: node:latest
     stage: deploy
     allow_failure: false
     script:
       - npm install
       - ./scripts/gitlab-ci_deploy.js
4. `git commit && git push` and it will deploy automatically the project to phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab does include it's own continuous integration. This was previously only available in the Enterprise Edition but it is now available in the Community Edition too.

Information: https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/

GitLab CI Documentation: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/README.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @anierzad - Do you know if there is any way to integrate it with either Cordova/PhoneGap or PhoneGap Build?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any experience with PhoneGap, only GitLab. However I have managed to find this comment by 'mauriziopinotti' where he states he's using GitLab CI and a script to automate builds with PhoneGap Build. https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/285#issuecomment-60508659

Comment: Oh, I see what they did there. In the past there was no way to integrate PhoneGap Build and GitLab and his script zipped the plugin and uploaded it to PhoneGap Build. Since then, they've actually added GitLab support, but they didn't integrate it with GitLab CI. While it's not entirely what I was looking for, thanks so much for your time :) (Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote you.)

Comment: No problem, I hope it leads to what you're looking for or at least helps out in the meantime :). I've upvoted your question; others might have more experience to help out.